# Targeting different releases when creating binary .debs

Tags: packaging

I am building `.deb` binary packages on ubuntu 14.04 but I want to target different releases including 14.04, 16.04 and 17.04.  Is it possible to build a binary package on ubuntu 14.04 that targets a later ubuntu release?

Having build the .deb on ubuntu 14.04, I have tried to install the package on ubuntu 17.04 but, when I run the installed executables, they all crash with different errors that suggest ABI incompatibilities.  For information, my package depends on the [openfoam-dev](https://openfoam.org/download/dev-ubuntu/) and the errors I encounter all relate to OpenFOAM.

Comment: Why do you need a "project" to create debs? Why not create them a conventional way using `debuild`?

Comment: By "project" I just mean other software projects.  I do indeed create the packages using `debuild`.

Comment: I never heard about travis-ci, and I see no reason to use anything else but `debuild`.

Comment: travis-ci is a continuous integration system that executes shell commands when you push commits to github.  The shell command I use to create the packages is `debuild`.  The compatibility problem exists regardless of travis-ci: my problem is due to differences between ubuntu releases.

Comment: It is unclear what the problem is. I build debs for many releases.

Comment: I've removed all references to travis-ci since it was only background information